# How to create basic model structure using artisan?

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I am new in Laravel and I want to create a model with all it's basic properties like fillable, table etc. using artisan.

I have explored some blogs but I have not found any way to create a model with basic fields. So, Is there any command to do it like we can do it in CodeIgniter 4?

Answer (score 1):

There is no automatic way to create table fields using artisan, what you can do instead is create the following and modify it:

```
php artisan make:model Blog -mcr
```

Read more on model options: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#generating-model-classes

**The above will create:**

1. A model named "blog"
2. A migration file - this is where you can modify/add fields to the database
3. A resource controller named "BlogController"

For migrations, you need to edit your migration file that it generated, see the documentation on how to do this: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#migration-structure

**Once you finish you can run the command:**

```
php artisan migrate
```

to push the changes of the migration file to the database.

---

Alternatively, you can always see what kind of options you have in artisan by doing:

```
php artisan make:model -help
```

[image]

And if you want to create everything related to the model, do the command:

```
php artisan make:model Blog -a
```

> Generate a migration, seeder, factory, policy, resource controller,
> and form request classes for the model

Comment: I don't want to create migration, resources. I just want to create a model with it's properties (like a structure). It should have the basic properties like: fillable, primaryKey, incrementing, keyType, timestamps etc. So, the typo in these properties can be ignored.

Comment: That can only be created inside the migration file, no where else, and not possible to create it in artisan. What is the issue with it?

Comment: I just don't want to make a typo into model properties while creation.